# How do I replace the fragmentactivity in the code below?

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

```
/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentActivity fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();//LessonPlanFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();//GradeBookFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();//StudentFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();//ReportsFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();//AppSettingsFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        ft.commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

I have tried using the support library but nothing helped. The error message reads "het method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, FragmentActivity).

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. You're trying to replace `Fragment` with `FragmentActivity` and this is impossible. You can only do that with `Fragment`s. For clarification `FragmetnActivity` acts as host Activity for Fragments in support library.